# Auto tagging a commit in Github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

When I make a chunk of changes I wish to tag as a version. 
I add `git tag v1.4` etc

How can I automatically add this to the commit I do for these changes, at the moment I am tagging the commit # after I have done the commit and pushed it.

ie:

```
git tag -a v1.2 cd8a721 -m "Message here"
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I automatically add this to the commit I do for these changes

You can do it withe GitHub web hooks.

Read about the events here: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#events

---

### ***`Note`***

Its much better to use annotated tag `git tag -a` since it will create a *commit like* tag with the same information as commit.

---

Another way id to have local hook - when you commit set the tag and then push the branches and the tags.

#### `post-commit hook`  (local hook)

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# get the last commit Id
lastCommit = $(git log -1 HEAD)

tag = <generate the tag message you want to set>

git tag -a ...

echo "                                         "
echo "                   |ZZzzz                "
echo "                   |                     "
echo "                   |                     "
echo "      |ZZzzz      /^\            |ZZzzz  "
echo "      |          |~~~|           |       "
echo "      |        |-     -|        / \      "
echo "     /^\       |[]+    |       |^^^|     "
echo "  |^^^^^^^|    |    +[]|       |   |     "
echo "  |    +[]|/\/\/\/\^/\/\/\/\/|^^^^^^^|   "
echo "  |+[]+   |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|    +[]|   "
echo "  |       |  []   /^\   []   |+[]+   |   "
echo "  |   +[]+|  []  || ||  []   |   +[]+|   "
echo "  |[]+    |      || ||       |[]+    |   "
echo "  |_______|------------------|_______|   "
echo "                                         "
echo "                                         "
echo "      You have just committed and tagged " 
echo "      your code                          "
```

Comment: So if I enter "git tag -a v1.5" then I make changes to files, add them and then do "git commit -m "Updated video content" and then "git push origin master" - that commit will then be tagged as v1.5?

Comment: Tag is simply a file which store a commit is with a readable string. You need to attach tag to a commit. You first need to make your changes and then tag them. In the hook i showed you above you get the commit id as parameter to the hook, use it to tag the commit.  first you commit then you tag

Comment: Added the lastCommit for you so you can use it to get the last commit you just made

Answer (score 2):

I tried using Github actions where I've added the below yaml file in the root directory `.github/workflows` or you can try adding the workflows from Github Actions like `setup new workflow` add the yaml

```
name: Auto Tag

on:
    push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Create tag
        id: tag
        run: echo "TAG=v1.0.${{ github.run_number }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Push tag
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "actions@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Actions"
          git tag ${{ env.TAG }}
          git push origin ${{ env.TAG }}
```

And from the Repository setting enable the permissions for Read & write

You can find the settings here: `Repository setting -> Actions -> General -> Workflow permissions`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ynD5.png)